# Crontab failed to scp

Tags: linux, cron, sshd

Am trying to send MySQL backup from server1   to server2  for backups storage

My command in shell..

scp myfile user@root:/file destination /

I use ssh-agent for paraphrase key pass..

In crontab normal just link to my shell When I use commands .. bash myshel.sh Is successful send but in crontab no will give Root mail saying Permission denied (publickey,gassapi-with -mic,password)

- - - - - root     /usr/Backup/myshell.sh

Comment: Try to find out who is actually running your script: put "ps -f" as first command and check its output.  Are you sure you've got the crontab syntax right? I doubt "root" should be there.

Comment: root  2107 2102 0 03:09 ?   00:00:00 /bin/bash -c /usr/Backu/send.sh  .    
root  2108 2101 0 03:09 ? 00:00:00 /bin/bash -c /usr/Backu/auto.sh  ..
root  2109 2106 0 03:09 ? 00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh -xoForwardAgent =no   -oPermitLocalCommand=n

Comment: # ps aux | grep crond | grep -v grep.
.
 root      2696  0.0  0.0 126336  1712 ?        Ss   May13   0:01 /usr/sbin/crond -n
#

Comment: Is it "/usr/Backup" or "/usr/Backu" ???   I cannot understand the "ps" command itself does not show.